# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an icon in a td

```
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="cd" value="'+currPat.id+'"/></td>
   <td><b>' + currPat.question + '</b><input type="text" class="saveEdit" value="'+currPat.question+'" style="display:none" /><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit pull-right" onclick="editable(this)"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save pull-right" style="display:none" onclick="saveEdit(this)"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right" onclick="deleteQuestion('+currPat.id+')"></i></td>
   <td>
      <select name="questionType" id="questionType" class="qType QSelect">
         <option value="">--Select--</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td width="35%" class="Fsize12 out" id=a'+ currPat.id +'><a href="#" class="checkbox-inline" onclick="getModal(this)">Get Options</a></td>
   <td><input type=hidden id=optionInputa'+currPat.id+' type=text/></td>
</tr>
```

In the above td there is  icon `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save pull-right" style="display:none" onclick="saveEdit(this)"></i>` and this saveEdit function

```
function saveEdit(qid)
    {
        var questionName=$('.saveEdit').val();
        alert(questionName);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: projectUrl+"saveEdit",  
            data:{question:questionName,questionID:qid},
            success:function (data1) {
                location.reload();
            }
}); 
    }
```

When ever I click on the save edit icon then I get the following error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

control goes till alert line

```
var questionName=$('.saveEdit').val();
            alert(questionName);
```

because I alert comes but after that the error comes and it does not send data to server

Can any body please tell me what may be the issue?

Comment: what is implemetation of : location.reload() .. Update your question so

Comment: @AbdennourToumi sorry I did not understand

Comment: success:function (data1) {
                location.reload();
            } ... What is location.reload=function(){........} .. is it native code or you do customization

Comment: @AbdennourToumi https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload

Comment: @AbdennourToumi It will just refresh the page when the ajax call is success.Do you think will this be a problem?I have some 5 ajax function in the same page and in every sucess part I have written location.reload();

Comment: @A.Wolff : please read deeply my last comment

Comment: Can you console log `questionName`, `qid`, `projectUrl`?

Comment: @kabamaru alert(questionName) shows me the questionName

Comment: I mean are all of them correctly set in you scope?
Another thing. Put a console log before `location.reload()` and report what it does.

Comment: @kabamaru I have removed location.reload() everywhere but still the same

Comment: Sorry I just saw you said it doesn't execute the ajax call

Comment: How about the other two vars qid, projectUrl?

Comment: if success: function(data1) is reloading the page on success, what is the data1 parameter for??

Comment: @kabamaru I get qid and projectUrl

Comment: @Hawk I have just written function (data1),It does not have any part to play

Comment: It might sound stupid but could you try renaming your function and the reference to it to let's say saveEditTest()?

Comment: @kabamaru yes sure I will try that way too

Answer (score 0):

This error is always brought up when your a function(either recursive or with a loop) causes an infinite loop. There is a high possibility that your function(saveEdit) is causing an infinite loop of some sort and the console throws an exception.

I would place my bets on your saveEdit function being called recursively endlessly and that is the reason that you are getting the error.